# HTML hidden td takes white space in IE6

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I am developing one JavaScript script the will hide and show the `td` on the my `button` click.

When I am trying to hide the `td` than `IE6` hide the td and put the some spaces there but however my code is working on the all the latest morder browser even the `latest IE`.

My code:

```
data = getElementsByClassName("data", "td", myElement);
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    td = data[i];                        
    tr = td.parentNode;
    for (j = 0; j < tr.childNodes.length; j++) {        
        tr.childNodes[j].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here I wrote my own `getElementsByClassName` method becusae the `IE6` does not support it and I want the `IE6` support. above code works find in all other browsers except the `IE6` browser.

In IE6 my table look like this:

[image]

And in other browsers

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you put your codes in fiddle?

Comment: I already put the main `code block` to the question? and by the way you have the IE6 ?

Comment: Did you try using `Element.nodeType`? An HTML line break creates a white space too.

Comment: @PHPglue, no I does not try it. Even I does not know about the `Element.nodeType` Thanks let me to give it try.

Comment: I've tried it. If you put a space or a line break between HTML Elements a white space is created. Try this `<span>wow</span>` now break the line in your editor then put `<span>WTF</span>`. Now try it like this `<span>wow</span><span>WTF</span>` and note the lack of white space.

Comment: Thank you @PHPglue. It may be happen. Can you please provide some links that help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: You just have to leave the white spaces or line breaks in or out. Either that or use PHP's output buffering, but that's another language.

Comment: I bet it breaks in Netscape Navigator 4 too.. Why the IE6 support? It's *long* dead.

Comment: @PHPglue. You I put the line of code in it `tr.childNodes[j].style.innerHTML=""` ? Sorry I does not get you, how can I leave the white spaces or line breaks in or out? Please provide the some little code.

Comment: On the next click of `button` I have to display back that `td`.

Comment: I think you should look at this http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t71

Comment: @YOU, thanks, I already tried it but is does not works.

Answer (score 0):

Try collapsing them:

```
tr.childNodes[j].style.visibility = "collapse";
tr.childNodes[j].style.display = "none";
```

And it wouldn't hurt, if you'd also set the display-property.

---

If you later want to reactivate the cells, you could reverse it:

```
tr.childNodes[j].style.visibility = "visible";
tr.childNodes[j].style.display = "table-cell";
```

---

Should this not work for any reason, 
we should find out why there is still the gap.
Could you use the IE-Inspector/Dev-Tools (F12) and find out where the gap comes from?

I could imagine the padding/margin/border-properties are the issue here,
or that this is a problem with the legendary [hasLayout-issue](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-haslayout-property/).

Comment: Thanks, Can I also have to put the `tr.childNodes[j].style.display = "none";` ?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, but for research purpose you could first just try this and let me/us know if it worked :)

Comment: Okay, What I have to do when I want to display them back on the screen ?

Comment: Oh sorry, Its look like `IE6` does not support the `visibility = "collapse"`, I got the following error on the `IE6` : `Could not get the visibility property, Invalid argument.`

Comment: By the way `IE6` also does not support the `table-cell` argument for the display.

Comment: What is really weird — both things. The default display-property should be `table-cell`, what does IE6 say is the default?   
And also the visibility-property should be available since IE5: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531180(v=vs.85).aspx   
I can take a deeper look tonight. If you find something out, let me know!

Comment: `IE6` does not support or provide the facility for  `Inspector/Dev-Tools (F12)`.

Comment: The default value of `tr.childNodes[j].style.display` in `IE6` is `null`, It simply does not return anything.

Comment: You can check out here: http://caniuse.com/#search=visibility it shows that in CSS 2.1 properties `visibility (visible | hidden)`.

Comment: You also shared the `MSDN` links https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531180(v=vs.85).aspx this link with me, You can also check there that `collapse` come in the image in the `IE8`.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 gets text Nodes and comment Nodes. Perhaps you should try this:

```
var doc = document;
function getElementsByClassName(className){
  if(doc.getElementsByClassName){
    return doc.getElementsByClassName(className);
  }
  var r = [], all = doc.getElementsByTagName('*');
  for(var i=0,l=all.length; i<l; i++){
    var ai = all[i];
    if(ai.className === className){
      r.push(ai);
    }
  }
  return r;
}

var data = getElementsByClassName('data');
for(var i=0,l=data.length; i<l; i++){
  var kids = data[i].parentNode.childNodes;
  for(var n=0,q=kids.length; n<q; n++){
    var kid = kids[n];
    if(kid.nodeType !== 1){
      kid.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But it still does not work. It gave the same output.